# Dump favorites of Internet Explorer into a file

Tags: internet-explorer, api, dump, bookmarks, favorites

I'd like to have users' sending me their Internet Explorer favorites.
 How can I achieve this ? Using XMLHTTPRequest() could work but how can I do the dump part ?

thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write Win32 code to enumerate the shortcut files in the [favorites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28VS.85%29.aspx) [folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then use the appropriate [COM goo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28VS.85%29.aspx) to crack open the data in the .url files themselves.